# Unity Instantiate how to manage the cloned objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management, instantiation

Following a 2D game tutorial for creating monsters the spawner script looks like this

```
public class MonsterSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] monsterReference;

    private GameObject spawnedMonster;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform leftPos, rightPos;

    private int randomIndex;
    private int randomSide;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnMonsters());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnMonsters() {

        while (true) {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 5));

            randomIndex = Random.Range(0, monsterReference.Length);
            randomSide = Random.Range(0, 2);

            spawnedMonster = Instantiate(monsterReference[randomIndex]);

            // left side
            if (randomSide == 0)
            {

                spawnedMonster.transform.position = leftPos.position;
                spawnedMonster.GetComponent<Monster>().speed = Random.Range(4, 10);

            }
            else
            {
                // right side
                spawnedMonster.transform.position = rightPos.position;
                spawnedMonster.GetComponent<Monster>().speed = -Random.Range(4, 10);
                spawnedMonster.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);

            }
}}}
```

**my question:** every 1-5 seconds a new monster is being cloned where does the object memory management happens and how can I handle/manage/change a specific object (in C# I would have a list and can reach each object through myMonsters[i])

**Editing Note:** I wish to know if there is a way to get and manage their memory (lets say destroy them) without changing the code from the tutorial (lets say if I want to create a new game manager class)

Comment: Instantiate creates a new gameobject which gets added to the hierarchy. You can either save the gameobject in a list. So add a `public List<GameObject> spawnedMonsters` and then add the reference to the spawned monster to the list after the instantiate in your `SpawnMonsters`. You can also get them by other methods as they are still in your hierarchy. Using a `GameObject.Find` for example could work but this is rather slow.

Comment: As far as the memory management goes that's handled by unity. As long as it exists in the hierarchy it uses memory. To destroy a gameobject in the hierarchy you have to call a Destroy(monsterGameObject) on it.

Comment: @Lieke Is there a direct access to objects in hierarchy from code?

Comment: Yes there is. There are a lot of way but the easiest is with the `Gameobject.Find` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html or the `FindObject` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html . These are quite slow though so you might want to cache the results. Also if you want to get the gameobject on which the current monobehaviour is on you can use `this.gameObject`.

Comment: You can also loop through the children of the current gameobject by using `foreach(Transform child in this.transform){}`. And you can get the root gameobjects with this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.GetRootGameObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate creates the object as a gameobject in the scene. The memory is managed in the scene hierarchy. As long as it's a gameobject in the scene the data is stored in it.

To keep the references to the gameobject you'll have to add an list of Gameobjects and then add the instantiated gameobjects to that list. To destroy the gameobject however you'll have to call a `Destroy(monster)`.

I've added to your code and added a list to all the spawned monsters. I've also added a part that destroys the monsters when there are more then 3 monsters in the scene.

Quick note: I've made everything public as it is often easier to debug, as you can see all the values in real time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MonsterSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] monsterReference;

    public GameObject spawnedMonster;
    public List<GameObject> previouslySpawnedMonsters = new List<GameObject>();

    public Transform leftPos, rightPos;

    public int randomIndex;
    public int randomSide;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnMonsters());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnMonsters()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 5));
            if (previouslySpawnedMonsters.Count > 3)
            {
                //get the monster to destroy
                GameObject monsterToDestroy = previouslySpawnedMonsters[0];

                //destroy the monster if it was spawned last round
                Destroy(monsterToDestroy);

                //remove the reference to the monster from our list of monsters
                previouslySpawnedMonsters.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            randomIndex = Random.Range(0, monsterReference.Length);
            randomSide = Random.Range(0, 2);

            spawnedMonster = Instantiate(monsterReference[randomIndex]);
            spawnedMonster.name = "monster " + count;
            count++;
            previouslySpawnedMonsters.Add(spawnedMonster);

            // left side
            if (randomSide == 0)
            {
                spawnedMonster.transform.position = leftPos.position;
                spawnedMonster.GetComponent<Monster>().speed = Random.Range(4, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                // right side
                spawnedMonster.transform.position = rightPos.position;
                spawnedMonster.GetComponent<Monster>().speed = -Random.Range(4, 10);
                spawnedMonster.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```